# Is there a way to use variables within URLs of slack workflows actions?

Tags: slack

I'm setting up a workflow that takes in a text variable I'd like to use in a later link.

For example, I ask for "Api Name", and then want to send a message that *both* references the api name as well as constructs a url (e.g. [http://swagger.io/docs/"Api](http://swagger.io/docs/%22Api) Name")

The problem I encounter is the links come up in plaintext if I just try to include that url as plaintext example as above. If I use the editor to try and add a link, the variable is not available.

My next thought was to try and edit the workflow json to supply some markdown in there, but it looks like the richtext is constructed from a series of elements.
A link looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "link",
    "url": "https://swagger.io/collections/",
    "text": "(Link)"
},
```

And a token looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "workflowtoken",
    "id": "<some uuid>==user",
    "property": "",
    "data_type": "user",
    "style": null
},
```

If I merely make the link plaintext and try to append the variable after the prefix I get something like this:

```
{
    "type": "text",
    "text": "https://swagger.io/thing/",
    "style": {
        "unlink": true
    }
},
{
    "type": "workflowtoken",
    "id": "<uuid>==text",
    "property": "",
    "data_type": "text",
    "style": null
},
```

So maybe if we knew all the values `"type"` could be that would help?

Not sure where to go from here. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: have same requirement

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: No, ended up just going with plaintext

Answer (score 5):

Here is an answer from Slack Support Service:

> We don't yet support Workflow variables outputted in links, I'm
> afraid.
>
> This is feedback we hear quite a bit so hopefully it's the something
> the team will consider implementing in the future.